# How can I generate all permutations of an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, algorithm, arrays, permutation

What's the best (elegant, simple, efficient) way to generate all `n!` permutations of an array in perl?

For example, if I have an array `@arr = (0, 1, 2)`, I want to output all permutations:

```
0 1 2
0 2 1
1 0 2
1 2 0
2 0 1
2 1 0
```

It should probably be a function that returns an iterator (lazy/delayed evaluation because `n!` can become so impossibly large), so it can be called like this:

```
my @arr = (0, 1, 2);
my $iter = getPermIter(@arr);
while (my @perm = $iter->next() ){
    print "@perm\n";
}
```

Comment: If you want to write your own, a recursive algorithm s.t. it would pick one item out of the array, and make the call to itself with the smaller array, until the array's of size one. It should be quite clean.

Comment: Perlmonks has some examples: [http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503904](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503904)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [perlfaq4](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq4.html): ["How do I permute N elements of a list?"](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-permute-N-elements-of-a-list):

---

Use the List::Permutor module on CPAN. If the list is actually an array, try the Algorithm::Permute module (also on CPAN). It's written in XS code and is very efficient:

```
use Algorithm::Permute;

my @array = 'a'..'d';
my $p_iterator = Algorithm::Permute->new ( \@array );

while (my @perm = $p_iterator->next) {
   print "next permutation: (@perm)\n";
}
```

For even faster execution, you could do:

```
use Algorithm::Permute;

my @array = 'a'..'d';

Algorithm::Permute::permute {
    print "next permutation: (@array)\n";
} @array;
```

Here's a little program that generates all permutations of all the words on each line of input. The algorithm embodied in the permute() function is discussed in Volume 4 (still unpublished) of Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming and will work on any list:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
# Fischer-Krause ordered permutation generator

sub permute (&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    my @idx = 0..$#_;
    while ( $code->(@_[@idx]) ) {
        my $p = $#idx;
        --$p while $idx[$p-1] > $idx[$p];
        my $q = $p or return;
        push @idx, reverse splice @idx, $p;
        ++$q while $idx[$p-1] > $idx[$q];
        @idx[$p-1,$q]=@idx[$q,$p-1];
    }
}


permute { print "@_\n" } split;
```

The Algorithm::Loops module also provides the NextPermute and NextPermuteNum functions which efficiently find all unique permutations of an array, even if it contains duplicate values, modifying it in-place: if its elements are in reverse-sorted order then the array is reversed, making it sorted, and it returns false; otherwise the next permutation is returned.

NextPermute uses string order and NextPermuteNum numeric order, so you can enumerate all the permutations of 0..9 like this:

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw(NextPermuteNum);

my @list= 0..9;
do { print "@list\n" } while NextPermuteNum @list;
```

Answer (score 22):

I suggest you use [List::Permutor](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Permutor):

```
use List::Permutor;

my $permutor = List::Permutor->new( 0, 1, 2);
while ( my @permutation = $permutor->next() ) {
    print "@permutation\n";
}
```

Comment: Is that a more permanent link? More canonical? Or just different?

Comment: More permanent (it handles a change of main author gracefully).

Comment: I like how the author's example on cpan includes ```my $perm``` :P

Answer (score 14):

You could use [Algorithm::Permute](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute) and maybe [Iterating Over Permutations](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol3_3/tpj0303-0010.html) (The Perl Journal, Fall 1998) is an interesting read for you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter the length of the string - ";
my $n = <> + 0;

my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } glob "{0,1,2}" x $n;

foreach my $key ( keys %hash ) {
    print "$key\n";
}
```

Output: This will give the all possible combinations of the numbers. You can add the logic to filter out the unwanted combinations.

```
$ perl permute_perl.pl 
Enter the length of the string - 3
101
221
211
100
001
202
022
021
122
201
002
212
011
121
010
102
210
012
020
111
120
222
112
220
000
200
110
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Iterator::Array::Jagged](https://metacpan.org/pod/Iterator::Array::Jagged).

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at an [algorithm for generating permutations in lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Lexicographical_order_generation), which is how I recently solved [Problem 24](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=24).  When the number of items in the array grows large, it becomes expensive to store and sort permutations later on.

It looks like `List::Permutor`, which was suggested by Manni, generates numerically sorted permutations.  That's what I'd go with using Perl.  Let us know how it turns out.

Answer (score 2):

A pure-Perl answer, in case of wanting to get fancier than the CPAN modules allow:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

print "(@$_)\n" for permutate('a'..'c');

sub permutate {
  return [@_] if @_ <= 1;
  map {
    my ($f, @r) = list_with_x_first($_, @_);
    map [$f, @$_], permutate(@r);
  } 0..$#_;
}

sub list_with_x_first {
  return if @_ == 1;
  my $i = shift;
  @_[$i, 0..$i-1, $i+1..$#_];
}
```

prints:

```
(a b c)
(a c b)
(b a c)
(b c a)
(c a b)
(c b a)
```

To explain the densely-written code a bit:

- `$_` is the value for each element of the list in a `map`. `@$_` treats that value as an array-ref.
- `@_` is the array of arguments to a function, and `$#_` is highest index in that array.
- The last expression in `list_with_x_first` (which first takes an index `$i`, then a list of other arguments), returns the other arguments but with the `$i`-th one first, then the previous ones, then the ones after.

To capture the results of calling `permutate`: `my @results = permutate(@input_list);`

Comment: What does @$_  and $#_ means?

Comment: How can I store the permutations in a variable?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your second question is an extremely basic Perl question.