# Reformulate a string query in perl

Tags: perl

How do i reformulate a string in perl?

For example consider the string "Where is the Louvre located?"

How can i generate strings like the following:

"the is Louvre located"
"the Louvre is located"
"the Louvre located is"

These are being used as queries to do a web search.

I was trying to do something like this:

Get rid of punctuations and split the sentence into words.
my @words = split / /, $_[0];

I don't need the first word in the string, so getting rid of it.
shift(@words);

And then i need move the next word through out the array - not sure how to do this!!

Finally convert the array of words back to a string.

Answer (score 1):

1. [How can I generate all permutations of an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635768)
2. Then use [`join`](http://p3rl.net/join) to glue each permutation array back together into a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat more verbose example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;


my $str = "Where is the Louvre located?";

# split into words and remove the punctuation
my @words = map {s/\W+//; $_} split / /, $str;

# remove the first two words while storing the second
my $moving = splice @words, 0 ,2;


# generate the variations
my @variants;
foreach my $position (0 .. $#words) {

    my @temp = @words;
    splice @temp, $position, 0, $moving;
    push @variants, \@temp;

}

print Dumper(\@variants);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my @head;
my ($x, @tail) = @words;
while (@tail) {
    push @head, shift @tail;
    print join " ", @head, $x, @tail;
};
```

Or you can just "bubble" $x through the array: $words[$n-1] and words[$n]

```
foreach $n (1..@words-1) { 
    ($words[$n-1, $words[$n]) = ($words[$n], $words[$n-1]);
    print join " ", @words, "\n";
};
```