# Perl: Using glob for permutation of values in an array with a userdefined length

Tags: perl, permutation

I just read

[How can I generate all permutations of an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635768/how-can-i-generate-all-permutations-of-an-array-in-perl)
http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=503904
and
https://metacpan.org/module/Algorithm::Permute

I want to create all possible combinations with a userdefined length of values in an array.

perlmonks did it like this:

```
@a= glob "{a,b,c,d,e,1,2,3,4,5}"x 2;
for(@a){print "$_ "}
```

and this works fine, but instead of `"{a,b,c,d,e,1,2,3,4,5}"` I would like to use an array

i tried this:

```
@a= glob @my_array x $userinput ;
for(@a){print "$_ "}
```

but it didn't work, how can I do that? Or how can I limit the length of permutation within Algorithm::Permute ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply generate the string from the array:

```
my @array = ( 'a' .. 'e', 1 .. 5 );
my $stringified = join ',', @array;
my @a = glob "{$stringified}" x 2;

say 0+@a;             # Prints '100';
say join ', ', @a;    # 'aa, ab, ac, ad ... 53, 54, 55'
```

---

One could also use a CPAN module. Like [`List::Gen`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aGen):

```
use List::Gen 'cartesian';

my @permutations = cartesian { join '', @_ } map [ $_ ], ( 'a'..'e', 1..5 ) ;
```

Comment: hm some how it doesnt work exactly, the first value is missing, and the ' ' are missing and the first { does not appear :>

Comment: Ah, okay i get it... but my Array get the values from a textfile, and those are A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and "." "," "-" - i think this causes the error?