# All possible combinations with key

Tags: perl

Say I have a hash:

```
1 => 1
2 => abc
3 => xyz
```

In Perl, how can I give a string like 211, and get all the possible combinations according to that hash: abc11, 1abc1, 11abc etc...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635768/how-can-i-generate-all-permutations-of-an-array-in-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several list permutation modules on CPAN, many in the question linked above: [How can I generate all permutations of an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635768/how-can-i-generate-all-permutations-of-an-array-in-perl)

Using the [List::Permutor](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::Permutor) module:

```
my $template = 211;

my %strings = (
    1 => 1,
    2 => 'abc',
    3 => 'xyz',
);

use List::Permutor ();

my $perm = List::Permutor->new(split //, $template);

my %seen;
while (my @set = $perm->next) {
    my $str = join '' => @strings{@set};
    say $str unless $seen{$str}++;
}
```

which prints:

```
abc11
1abc1
11abc
```

Do note that you will have problems using bare numbers in your template if you go beyond the keys `0 .. 9`.  (does `10` mean `10` or `1,0`...).  You should probably change your template to have a record separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like, get the digits from the string, and loop and build the string :

```
my @digits = ($str =~ /(\d)/g);
my $val;
foreach (@digits) {
    # %values holds key/value pairs
    $val .= $values{$_};
}
```