# What's the mistake in my recursive subroutine?

Tags: string, perl, loops, recursion, subroutine

This subroutine generates string combinations of the letters using the letters from A to the Mth letter of the Alphabet with length N.

```
sub genString
{
   my($m,$n,$str,$letter,$temp,$i) = @_;
   if($n == 0){
      $letter = chr(ord("A")+($i+=1));
       if($temp == 1){ print "$str\n"; }
       else{
          for($j = 0 ; $j < temp-1 ; $j++){
             if(ord(substr($str,$j,1)) < ord(substr($str,$j+1,1))){$do_print = 1;}
             else{
                $do_print = 0;
                break;
             }
          }
       if($do_print == 1){ print "$str\n"; }
       }
   }
   else{
       for($j = ord($letter) ; $j < ord($letter)+$m ; $j++){
           genString($m,$n-1,$str.chr($j),$letter,$temp,$i);
      }
   }
}
&genString($m,$n,$str,"A",$n,0);
```

Example:
Input: M=4; N=3;
Output: ABC ABD ACD BCD

I tried similar to this in Ruby and it works, but in Perl, it's an infinite loop, and I don't know why. I'm new here in Perl. What should I do? (Sorry if my code is kinda lengthy)

Comment: It helps if you cut and paste your actual code

Comment: Is `temp-1` a typo? I should be `$temp-1`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635768/how-can-i-generate-all-permutations-of-an-array-in-perl, reference to [perlfaq](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-permute-N-elements-of-a-list-)

Comment: And there is no `break` in Perl, you most likely want to use `last` there.

Comment: Please make sure your code can compile before posting it here. See `perldoc perlrun` and read about the -c switch.

Answer (score 3):

Please always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;` in your code, especially when posting code and asking for help. Also always declare local variables with `my`.

In this case even without having tried it I'm pretty sure something like `$j` referring to a global variable is causing you a lot of headache -- something `use strict` would have caught.

Answer (score 3):

By default, variables are globals in perl (though undeclared and unqualified use of them will be prevented by `use strict`).  For your recursion to work, you'll need to make some of them lexical, for instance, changing:

```
for($j = 0 ; $j < temp-1 ; $j++){
```

to

```
for (my $j = 0; $j < $temp-1; $j++) {
```

or better yet, just

```
for my $j (0..$temp-2) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very hard to read. I can't understand the algorithm, and I don't see the purpose of so many parameters to the subroutine, especially `$temp` which doesn't appear to change, and you don't say what its initial value is set to in the outermost call.

This code appears to do what you want, with a similar algorithm

```
use strict;
use warnings;

genString(4, 3);

sub genString {

   my ($m, $n, $str, $i) = @_;

   if ($n == 0) {
     print $str, "\n";
   }
   else {
     for my $off ($i // 0 .. $m - $n) {
       $str //= '';
       genString($m, $n-1, $str.chr(ord('A') + $off), $off+1);
     }
   }
}
```

**output**

```
ABC
ABD
ACD
BCD
```