# Finding all combinations/permutations of letters in a string using Perl

Tags: perl, permutation

Imagine that I have a string, `abc`. I want to find all of the combinations/permutations that can be created from the letters in that string.

For example:

```
abc
bac
acb
cba
...
```

How can I do this with Perl?

Answer (score 5):

First, given your example, you are trying to generate *permutations* rather than *combinations*: the order of the elements matter for the former, but not for the latter. This means that `abc` and `cba` are the same combination, but different permutations.

As to how to do it, I suggest to transform your string into an array (`split //, $str` will do), then to generate the permutations of this array (see below), and then to `join` the permutations to get back to strings. As to how to compute the permutations, you can use a few of the cpan modules that exists to do so: have a look at [How can I generate all permutations of an array in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/635768/4990392) for inspiration. For instance, using [`Algorithm::Combinatorics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Combinatorics):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(permutations);

my $string = "abc";

my @perms = map { join "", @$_ } permutations([split //, $string]);

say for @perms;
```

If performance is a concern, then you should probably use [`Algorithm::Permute`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Algorithm::Permute) instead: it should be faster. Some answers of the question I linked above show how to use this module.